# A table value places a checkmark in a checkbox on a form

Tags: ms-access, checkbox

How do you have MS Access place a checkmark in a checkbox control based off a value in a table?

Comment: If the checkbox is always going to be the same result based on the value stored elsewhere, you don't -- that's storing the same data twice.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to bind the form to a query or table and bind the control to the relevant field (column).